# How to return information from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium, jsoup, pageobjects

I am setting up a basic page object pattern automation test. Open google, input search, click link from results and return info. I've got it down to where I navigate to the page I need to pull the info from. I need to locate the contact info from the bottom of www.sahipro.com and return it to the console of my test class. I can't gather only the emails and number, I'm getting html extra stuff. And I cant figure out how to call that page results in my test class.

I can't parse out only the contact text and I do not know how to bring that over to my separate test class. I'm fairly new to this so my knowledge is beginner at best.

```
try {

//Get Document object after parsing the html from given url.
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://https://sahipro.com/").get();

Element support = document.text("support@sahipro.com"); //Get Support
print("  Support Email: " + support); //Print support.

}catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

print("done");
}

public static void print(String string) {
System.out.println(string);
}
```

I'm returning the information but it's coming in in the html format. 
    Console:

```
running...
Support Email: <html>



<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" 
content="0;url=http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php
origURL=http://https%2Fsahipro.com%2F&amp;bc=">
</head>
<body>
support@sahipro.com
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What info do you want to extract from the page? Support@sahipro.com or the href of the node

Comment: `http://https://sahipro.com/` looks odd. That should probably be `https://sahipro.com/`.

Comment: @edwin I want to extract just the support@sahipro.com

Comment: @howlger I saw that too. For whatever reason the way I have produces a cleaner result that the way you pointed out. Your way I get all of this and more in the console.     "<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>..."

Comment: @Regg [`text(String)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text-java.lang.String-) sets a text, but I guess you want get the element that contains the specified text via [`getElementsContainingText`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsContainingText-java.lang.String-) or via [`getElementsContainingOwnText`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsContainingOwnText-java.lang.String-) instead, right?

Comment: @howlger Yes, I think. I don't know if it'd make it easier but there's a grid containing all the info I need to extract. It's a contact us section that has the support & sales email and a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

The method text from class Element of jsoup gets text from the given node. Your code is getting text from document root. To get text of a specific node in your case use the select method to get a specific node. 
 Use

```
 document.select("a[^='mailto:']")[0].text();
```

Applying the command to your code

```
try {

 //Get Document object after parsing the html from given url.
      Document document = 
      Jsoup.connect("http://https://sahipro.com/").get();

       String support = document.select("a[^='mailto:']")[0].text();
        String phone = document.select("a[^='tel:']")[0].text();

      print("  Support Email: " + support + " Support Phone: "+ phone ); 

     }catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

     print("done");
 }

public static void print(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
 }
```

Comment: When I try to apply that code I'm getting this error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Elements"